# Reversing Linkedlist using Stack : wrong output

Tags: c++, templates

**Reverse List using Stack**
I am very new to C++ template, and learning it through small programming.
I'm definitely not understanding what is wrong in logic at all.
Here is the code.

```
 .
 .
 .
 .



template<typename T>
void Display(node<T> *front)
{
    node<T> *temp = front;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        cout << temp->data << "  ";
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

template<typename T>
void Reverse(node<T> *front)
{
    node<T> *temp = front;
    stack< node<T>* > s;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        s.push(temp);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    node<T> *curr = s.top();
    front = curr;
    s.pop();
    while (!s.empty())
    {
        curr->next = s.top();
        s.pop();
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    curr->next = NULL;
}

int main()
{
    node<int> *front = NULL;
    int size, no;
    cout << "Enter the size of list ";
    cin >> size;
    for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the " << i << " element " << endl;
        cin >> no;
        front = new node<int> ( no , front);
    }
    Display(front);
    Reverse(front);
    cout << " Reverse of the linklist is "<<endl;
    Display(front);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Output :
Enter the size of the list : 3
Enter 1 element : 2
Enter 2 element : 4
Enter 3 element : 6
6 4 2
Reverse of the linklist is
6

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP needs to use the debugger to debug the code.

Comment: One hint: what are the implications of passing the address of front by value to the `Reverse` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are keeping the pointer to node that became tail:

[image]

You can wrap your `node` in `list` that will know how to properly reverse the order of elements and will know which is the head. Also will manage memory allocated for nodes so you won't have memleaks.

Comment: Sorry friend ,I am trying hard but I am not getting where I am making mistake. Can you help me ??

Comment: @Tushar from function `Reverse()` return `front`. Then in main write `front = Reverse(front);`